# Should a PUT identifier come from the URL or from the HTTP request data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, put, restful-url

This question is probably a dupe, but I couldn't find a similar one (not sure exactly what to search for).

Say I have a restful resource URL like this:

```
/my/items/6/edit
```

There is a form at this page which allows me to edit my #6 item. When I submit the form, it POSTS to `/my/items/6`, with a PUT X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

My question is, where should the server handler get the value "6" from? Should it get it from the URL? Or from the HTTP POST data (say the id was rendered as a hidden input field on the form)?

It seems to me like it should come from the URL. However this makes it a little more trouble to get it out. For example in .NET MVC, you might get it like this from a controller action method:

```
var id = int.Parse(ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
```

...which seems like more trouble than it's worth. However, if we get it out of the HTTP POST data, then technically you could post/put data for my item #6 to `/my/items/7`, and the server would still save the item data under id #6.

Are there any standard practices here?

Comment: This ("/my/items/6/edit") is definetly not REST. Your form is not part of REST. With REST you 1) GET /my/items/6 and then 2) UPDATE my/items/6. See http://kellabyte.com/2011/09/04/clarifying-rest/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Guiding_principles_of_the_interface.

Comment: @jmclem.. suppose I send a GET request to /my/items/6. How should the web server know whether to return a read-only HTML page or an HTML form to edit the item?

Comment: never had to do this myself - I use REST for data flow - but I would try to make use of HTTP content negociation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) with e.g. 'Accept: text/html' or 'Accept: application/json' or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definitely come from the URL.  In ASP.NET MVC, if you had a route defined like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "/my/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    new { controller = "items", action = "Index" }
);
```

You would be able to reference the ID from the ActionResult method signature, like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Index(int id, MyItemEditModel model)
{
    // id would be 6 if the URL was /my/items/6/
    // and the model need not contain the id
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of this a couple hours after I posted... definitely a duh moment. However I was talking about POST/PUT requests, so I have edited your answer slightly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190267/Controllers-and-Routers-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3

I'm not a .net developer, though best practice in all platforms is to map your URI template to controller. Router must parse and prepare such information and pass it to your function/method.